# How do I omit duplicates in a list?

Tags: python

I am currently trying to write a program that counts how many times a word occurs in an input. I am currently running into the following problem:

Take for example this:

```
list: ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green']
```

If I use a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(userinput)):
    list.count(userinput[i])
```

it would simply return: `1, 2, 1, 2`

How would I make it return: `1, 2, 1`, counting another occurrence only once?

Comment: Your Question is totally unclear.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if just the count in the form [1,2,1] would be of much meaning. Ideally you would need a dictionary with the count of each element like this:

```
l = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green']
from collections import Counter
Counter(l)
```

You get

```
Counter({'blue': 1, 'green': 2, 'red': 1})
```

If you wish to do this without Counter, try

```
 dict((item, l.count(item)) for item in l)
```

and you get

```
{'blue': 1, 'green': 2, 'red': 1}
```

Comment: this is probably the right answer... but it wasnt clear from OP's post if order mattered...as an aside your name reminds me of a problem i once had ... and then I had 2 problems

Comment: @ Joran Beasley, I agree. I just thought of an alternate that according to me made more sense. May be the OP just needs the output that he would get from your answer:)

Answer (score 1):

```
counts = []
seen = set()
for a_string in userinput_list: 
    if a_string not in seen: 
        print(a_string,"=",userinput_list.count(a_string))
        seen.add(a_string)
```

I guess ... theres better ways to do this but this should work

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best way.

```
userinput = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green']
set = set([])
for input in userinput :
    set.add(userinput.count(input))
print set
```

You get

```
set([1, 2])
```

Another Example,

```
userinput = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'green'] #Added green
set = set([])
for input in userinput :
    set.add(userinput.count(input))
print set
```

you get

```
set([1, 3])
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashTable where the key is the word and the value is a counter. 
Each time you see the word increase the counter, if it's a new word set the counter to one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> 
>>> def element_count(lst):
    count = defaultdict(int)
    for element in lst:
        count[element] += 1
    return list(count.values())

>>> 
>>> lst = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'green']
>>> element_count(lst)
[1, 1, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: since dicts do not preserve order... there is no way to tell what number in the returned list corresponds to which list entry :/

Comment: @JoranBeasley Well I wasn't completely sure if the OP needed that. If he need that, he should just use the dictionary.